# Switch case program does not give the output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int choice;
printf("Enter 1 for Programmers Name and ID\n");
printf("Enter 2 to Perform Integer Operation\n");
printf("Enter 3 to Perform Floating Point Operation\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);
system("CLS");

if (choice == 1)
    printf("Connor \n000000000\n");

else if (choice == 2)
{
    char c;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter operator:");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    getchar();
    printf("Enter two integer's :");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

    switch (c)
    {
    case '+':
        printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
        break;

    default:
        printf("The value of c = '%c'\n");
        system("pause");
        return(0);
    }
}
else if (choice == 3)
    printf("Enter two \n");


system("pause");
return(0);
}
```

I need a little help figuring out a small problem with the operations part of this code.......everything works out as in can put in the operator and the integers but I do not get the output from the switch.

Comment: Try putting `\n` at the end of each printf.

Comment: @user3386109 he doesn't get any output...so \n isn't the issue

Comment: Didn't read it through, but adding a `default` clause and printing out the value of `c` would be a good start of debugging.

Comment: What do you mean by "output from the switch"?

Comment: Try fflush to flush output

Comment: Coding style suggestion: although the `{ }` pairs are not required around the choice==1 and choice==3 `printf` statements, they're a good habit. It's easy to forget to add them if you add something to go with the `printf` statements later. On the other hand, the `{` after the `system("cls")` and the corresponding `}` before the `system("pause")` are superfluous. Grammer note: the plural of "integer" is "integers", not "integer's". Your professor may not be a grammar snob, but that will help you in other settings.

Comment: I added the default and it still goes to...well error now because i set it to that

Comment: `getchar(c);` is an error. You should get a compilation error. Pay attention to those, and fix any errors and warnings before proceeding.

Comment: `Default` should be `default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should definitely work

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

int choice;
printf("Enter 1 for Programmers Name and ID\n");
printf("Enter 2 to Perform Integer Operation\n");
printf("Enter 3 to Perform Floating Point Operation\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);
getchar();
if (choice == 1)

    printf("Connor \n000000000\n");


else if (choice == 2)


{
    char c;
    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter operator:");
    scanf("%c", &c);
    printf("Enter two integer's :");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
    switch (c)
    {

    case '+':
        printf("%d + %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
        break;
    case '-':
        printf("%d - %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
        break;
    case '*':
        printf("%d * %d = %d", num1, num2, num1*num2);
        break;
    case '/':
        printf("%d / %d = %d", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
        break;

    default:
        printf("The value of c = '%c'\n" , c);
        return(0);
    }

}
else if (choice == 3)
    printf("Enter two \n");

}
```

Comment: There I believe everything should be in order

Comment: no....here this is how it runs     press 2 > enter operation + > enter integers 2 2 > (leads to the default)

Comment: Thank you for all of the help and being patient with me

Comment: And yes your's also worked just did not load on my screen before i saw the other one

Comment: Oh didn't notice it was a best answer, thought it was just this solves the problem so i clicked both haha

Answer (score -1):

1. Change:

   ```
   scanf("%c", &c);
   getchar();
   ```

   to:

   ```
   scanf(" %c", &c);
   ```
2. Add an `\n` to each of these:

   ```
   printf("%d + %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
                       ^^
   ```
3. Actually provide a `char` when you tell `printf()` to print one:

   ```
   printf("The value of c = '%c'\n", c);
                                   ^^^
   ```

and it should work for you. Revised code, removing all the `system()` nonsense:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int choice;

    printf("Enter 1 for Programmers Name and ID\n");
    printf("Enter 2 to Perform Integer Operation\n");
    printf("Enter 3 to Perform Floating Point Operation\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if ( choice == 1 ) {
        printf("Connor \n000000000\n");
    }
    else if ( choice == 2 ) {
        char c;
        int num1, num2;

        printf("Enter operator:");
        scanf(" %c", &c);

        printf("Enter two integers :");
        scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

        switch ( c ) {

        case '+':
            printf("%d + %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 + num2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%d - %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 - num2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 * num2);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%d / %d = %d\n", num1, num2, num1 / num2);
            break;
        default:
            printf("The value of c = '%c'\n", c);
            break;
        }
    } else if ( choice == 3 ) {
        printf("Enter two \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Invalid choice.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with sample output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./cal
Enter 1 for Programmers Name and ID
Enter 2 to Perform Integer Operation
Enter 3 to Perform Floating Point Operation
2
Enter operator:*
Enter two integers :4 6
4 * 6 = 24
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Thank for the help sorry it came to you having to do that

Comment: No problem, we all have to start somewhere, and you made a pretty good attempt at it. Dealing with input/output is one of the trickier parts of learning C.